# Testimonials Animated Rotate objects around circle using CSS?

Tags: css, animation, geometry

[image]

I want to create one like this using css. Guys, Please help me..

Look at [this gif](https://timbdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/material-design-concept.gif) and get a idea above picture

Comment: Here is some help: look at the code for the website you got that GIF from and figure out how they did it. Attempt to create a duplicate. Debug as necessary.

Comment: @ecg8 Can not look at the code from that web site.it restricted. can you give me proper code for this?